# Error with Karma and Angular UI Router

Tags: angularjs, requirejs, jasmine, karma-runner, angular-ui-router

I'm new to using Karma and I'm trying to write a very simple unit test for a controller. I'm using angular-ui-router and whenever I try to run the test it says:

```
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module calendar due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module common due to:
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $stateProvider
```

My `main-test.js`:

```
(function (window, require) {
    "use strict";
    var allTestFiles, TEST_REGEXP;

    allTestFiles = [];
    TEST_REGEXP = /Test\.js$/;

    Object.keys(window.__karma__.files).forEach(function(file) {
        if (TEST_REGEXP.test(file)) {
            allTestFiles.push(file);
        }
    });

    allTestFiles.push("app");
    allTestFiles.push("angular-mocks");
    allTestFiles.push("angular-ui-router");

    require({
        baseUrl:'/base/src/main/modules',
        paths:{
            'jquery': '../../../bower_components/jquery/jquery',
            'jquery-ui': '../../../bower_components/jquery-ui/ui/jquery-ui',
            'jquery.ui.widget': '../../../bower_components/jquery-ui/ui/jquery.ui.widget',
            'bootstrap': '../../../bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap',
            'angular': '/base/bower_components/angular/angular',
            'angular-mocks': '/base/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks',
            'angular-sanitize': '/base/bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize',
            'ngUi': '/base/bower_components/angular-ui/build/angular-ui',
            'ui.bootstrap': '/base/src/main/external-libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.6.0-SNAPSHOT.min',
            'ngCalendar': '/base/bower_components/angular-ui-calendar/src/calendar',
            'angular-ui-router': '/base/bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router',
            'uikeypress': '/base/bower_components/angular-ui-utils/modules/keypress/keypress',
            'dtPicker': '/base/bower_components/eonasdan-bootstrap-datetimepicker/build/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min',
            'fileUpload': '/base/bower_components/blueimp-file-upload/js/jquery.fileupload',
            'fullcalendar': '/base/bower_components/fullcalendar/fullcalendar',
            'iframeTransport': '/base/src/main/external-libs/iframetransport/jquery.iframe-transport',
            'lodash': '/base/bower_components/lodash/dist/lodash',
            'moment': '/base/bower_components/momentjs/moment',
            'restangular': '/base/bower_components/restangular/dist/restangular',
            'typeahead': '/base/bower_components/typeahead.js/dist/typeahead'
        },
        shim:{
            'jquery': { deps: [], exports: 'jquery' },
            'jquery-ui': { deps: ['jquery'], exports: 'jquery-ui' },
            'jquery.ui.widget': { deps: ['jquery'], exports: 'jquery-ui-widget' },
            'bootstrap': { deps: ['jquery'], exports: 'bootstrap' },
            'angular': { deps: [], exports: 'angular' },
            'angular-mocks': { deps: ['angular'] },
            'angular-sanitize': { deps: ['angular'], exports: 'ngSanitize' },
            'ngUi': { deps: ['angular'], exports: 'ngUi' },
            'ui.bootstrap': { deps: ['angular', 'ngUi'], exports: 'ui-bootstrap' },
            'ngCalendar': { deps: ['jquery', 'jquery-ui', 'fullcalendar', 'angular'], exports: 'ngCalendar' },
            'angular-ui-router': { deps: ['angular', 'ngUi'], exports: 'angular-ui-router' },
            'uikeypress': { deps: ['angular', 'ngUi'], exports: 'uikeypress' },
            'dtPicker': { deps: ['jquery', 'bootstrap', 'moment'], exports: 'dtPicker' },
            'fileUpload': { deps: ['jquery', 'jquery-ui', 'bootstrap', 'iframeTransport'], exports: 'fileUpload' },
            'fullcalendar': { deps: ['jquery', 'jquery-ui'], exports: 'fullcalendar' },
            'iframeTransport': { deps: ['jquery', 'jquery-ui'], exports: 'iframeTransport' },
            'lodash': { deps: [], exports: 'lodash' },
            'moment': { deps: ['jquery'], exports: 'moment' },
            'restangular': { deps: ['angular', 'lodash'], exports: 'restangular' },
            'typeahead': {deps: ['jquery', 'bootstrap'], exports: 'typeahead'}
        }
    }, allTestFiles, function () {
        window.__karma__.start();
    }, function (err) {
        var failedModules = err.requireModules;
        console.log("err", err);

        if (failedModules && failedModules[0]) {
            throw new Error("Module couldn't be loaded: " + failedModules);
        } else {
            throw new Error("Unkown error:" + err);
        }
    });
}(window, require));
```

The `CalendarControllerTest.js` file:

```
define(['calendar/CalendarController'], function(CalendarController) {

    'use strict';
    describe('the CalendarController', function () {
        var calendarController, scope;

        beforeEach(function () {
            module('calendar');

            inject(['$rootScope', '$controller', function ($rootScope, $controller) {
                scope = $rootScope.$new();
                calendarController = $controller(CalendarController, {$scope: scope});
            }]);
        });
        it('should have two event sources', function () {
            expect(scope.eventSources.length).toBe(2);
        });
    });
});
```

I'm working off the template included in the ngStart seed project. My `calendar` and `common` modules use angular-ui-router and declare states

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is here:

`'angular-ui-router': { deps: ['angular', 'ngUi'], exports: 'angular-ui-router' },`

This should export `angular`

`'angular-ui-router': { deps: ['angular', 'ngUi'], exports: 'angular' },`

And here

```
'angular-sanitize': { deps: ['angular'], exports: 'ngSanitize' }
```

Should be:

```
'angular-sanitize': { deps: ['angular'], exports: 'angular' }
```

Well, actully almost all your shims are improper. You should `export` the global variable (i. e. namespace), to which library is bound.

For example

**myThirdPartyModule.js**

```
(function(window) {
   var namespace = {}
   // Declaration....

   window.myThirdPartyModule = namespace;
}(this))
```

will be shimmed like this:

```
'myThirdPartyModule': {exports: 'myThirdPartyModule' }
```

Read more about shim config [here](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-shim)

Comment: I removed all my exports as everything is an AMD module. It changed my error, but seems to have fixed this problem.